# Why this loop is not executed?

Tags: javascript

Just practicing some for loops and I'm not sure why it is outputting nothing:

```
['']
```

This is the code:

```
var text = "This is a long piece of Liam text with a bit of Liam text in the Liam";
var myName = "Liam";
var hits = [""]

for (var i=0; i >= text.length; i++)
{
   if (myName[i] === "L")
   {
       for (var j=i; j < (myName.length + i); j++)
       {
           hits.push(i);
       }
   }
}

if (hits.length === 0)
{
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}

else 
{
    console.log(hits);
}
```

I don't think my push function is actually pushing the letters into the array properly?

Comment: Why not just do `text.indexOf('Liam')`?

Comment: check the loop condition in your outer for loop

Comment: Is this just meant to find instances of `name`?

Comment: I don't know how this question got upvotes...

Comment: @sivatumma, same here, why on earth someone promote this kind of question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i >= text.length; i++)
```

should be

```
for (var i=0; i < text.length; i++)
```

Comment: This is what my first look at... Look at @frits van.. he is still continuing with his view and is getting upvotes ... Did you check if his view has a point btw..?

Comment: Thanks. That helped me fix it, there is also another problem with the for loop. I'll add an answer for that for others reference learning loops.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an FYI, you can do:

```
text.indexOf(myName) !== -1; // true if myName occurs in text
```

or, if you want to be really clever:

```
text.match(new RegExp("\b" + myName + "\b")); // \b = word boundary = amazing
// wont match "NotLiam", will match "Hi, I'm Liam."
```

Comment: Because you can totally practice for loops with this.

Answer (score 1):

for (var i=0; i >= text.length; i++)

actually means the variable i will start from 0 and every time before execution of the code block to check if the condition i >= text.length is met, if the condition doesn't hold, the code block will not be executed. The last part of i++ means after each iteration of the code block defined after, run this statement.

Since the text length appearing longer than 0, so the first check i (equals to 0) greater or equals to the text length (which is 69) fails and the push is never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i >= text.length; i++)
{
  if (myName[i] === "L")
   {
     for (var j=i; j < (myName.length + i); j++)
     {
       hits.push(i);
     }
   }
}
```

the foor loop is wrong

it should be:

```
  for (var i=0; i <= text.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i <= text.length; i++)
{
   if (text[i] === "L")
   {
       for (var j=i; j < (myName.length + i); j++)
       {
           hits.push(text[j]);
       }
   }
}
```

The code within the second nested for loop is also wrong - changed it from:

```
for (var j=i; j < (myName.length + i); j++)
       {
           hits.push(i);
       }
```